# Office365 REST API - Creating attachments on an existing event doesn't send meeting update requests to recipients

Tags: rest, graph, office365

API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/event_post_attachments

When we create attachments on an event, no meeting update request is sent out and as a consequence, the recipients don’t receive the updated meeting with the attachments. Any idea to go about how to handle this?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: I do not, but here's a simple repro: 1. Create event with attendees via OWA. 2. Use API above to create an attachment for the event using the organizers credentials. 3. You will notice that the attendees don't receive an update to the event.